# SharePoint 2013 Single form updating multiple lists

Tags: custom-form, related-list

I've a SharePoint 2013 site with multiple related lists (Parent/Child relation). What would be the best practice out there to create a SharePoint 2013 form to update all the lists at once?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit NewForm.aspx or EditForm.aspx and write custom code using jquery or javascript to add or edit data in any list by this way you can use same form to update all lists at once.

Comment: Hi Parag, Thank you for your answer. I'm not a programmer and I'm really doing my first steps in creating a form from multiple lists. I'll appreciate any specific advice that will help me to edit the NewForm and EditForm pages.

Comment: open NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx using Sharepoint designer select list where you want to add jquery or javascript . In  Forms tab there are NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx you can edit this file and your javascript or jquery code here.

To edit NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx please refer following url

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/09/20/how-to-create-custom-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx